# Magento 2 - How to use font awesome icons using cdn url?

Tags: magento2, cdn

I'm new to Magento 2.

I would like to know how to use font awesome icons in my magento 2 project particularly in linking the cdn url to my project where about would I add this link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use absolute url instead of relative url to import font in css file like :

```
../font/fontfilename => http://www.yourdomain/skin/frontend/namespace/theme/font/fontfilename
```

Comment: Hi Where Do i place this line of code?

Comment: Folder path :: /app/design/frontend/your themes package structure/web/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.css

Comment: According to Magento 2 and your folder structure you have to change the font url.

Comment: no others ways!

Answer (score 2):

To add external static resources like CSS, JavaScript, Web fonts (Fontawesome in this case), Please follow the steps below.

1. Go to this [link](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use) and copy the CDN URL of Fontawesome.
2. Find the file `app/design/frontend/{Themevendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` and paste the line below. (The line should be placed in the `head` tag and the value of `src_type` should be `url`.)

`<css src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" src_type="url"/>`

For details please visit this Magento 2 devdocs [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)